# What is a proper schema.org markup for an About us page about a brand?

Tags: schema.org, technical-seo, markup, knowledge-graph

I have a standalone website dedicated to a particular software brand of a parent development company.

I'm trying to optimize the About us page and schema.org markup so Google would show the Knowledge Panel about the **software brand**.

As numerous guides suggest, in such a case a proper markup type for the About us page is [Organization](https://schema.org/Organization).

What would be the correct way to organize the Organization markup for the software brand's About us page?

Here is an initial version I had in mind:

---

*Note*:

*Company_name ≠ Brand_name*

*Brand_name = Software_name*

---

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Corporation",
  "url": "https://www.brand.com/about-us/",
  "name": "Company_name",
  "description": "A description for the company.",
  "brand":
  [
    {
      "@type": "Thing",
      "name": "Brand_name",
      "description": "A description for the brand.",
      "mainEntityOfPage":
      {
        "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
        "name": "Software_name"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not nest the Brand inside `Corporation` on the Brand website. I would use an `Organization` object, citing the Company as the `parentOrganization`. You can keep the rest as is.

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Brand_name",
    "brand":
    [
      {
      "@type": "Thing",
      "name": "Brand_name",
      "description": "A description for the brand.",
      "mainEntityOfPage":
        {
          "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
          "name": "Software_name"
        }
      }
   ],
    "description": "A description of the Brand_name",
    "parentOrganization": "Company_name",
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "logo": "https://example.com/images/logo.png",
    "sameAs": [
        "https://twitter.com/brand_name",
        "https://github.com/brand_name",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/company/brand_name/"
    ]
}
```

Another way you could do this would be to nest `SoftwareApplication` inside `makesOffer`. You lose `Brand` though, as it is not expected inside `makesOffer`.

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Brand_name",
    "description": "A description of the Brand_name",
    "parentOrganization": "Company_name",
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "logo": "https://example.com/images/logo.png",
    "makesOffer": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "itemOffered" : {
            "@type" : "SoftwareApplication",
            "name" : "Software_name"
        }
    },
    "sameAs": [
        "https://twitter.com/brand_name",
        "https://github.com/brand_name",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/company/brand_name/"
    ]
}
```

See [SoftwareApplication](https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) & [makesOffer](https://schema.org/makesOffer)

Alternatively, if the About page doesn't contain any info about the software, it may be safer to just specify the relationship between the brand and the company. Then provide `SoftwareApplication` elsewhere (eg. home page or product page).

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Brand_name",
    "description": "A description of the Brand_name",
    "parentOrganization": "Company_name",
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "logo": "https://example.com/images/logo.png",
    "sameAs": [
        "https://twitter.com/brand_name",
        "https://github.com/brand_name",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/company/brand_name/"
    ]
}
```

Here's an example of a way I've written similar semantics that you might find useful:

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Example Software Company",
    "url": "https://example.com/",
    "logo": "https://example.com/logo.png",

    "hasOfferCatalog": {
        "@type": "OfferCatalog",
        "name": "Software as a service",
        "alternateName": "SaaS",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "itemOffered": {
                    "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
                    "name": "SalesFarce CRM",
                    "operatingSystem": "All",
                    "applicationCategory": "WebApplication",
                    "aggregateRating": {
                      "@type": "AggregateRating",
                      "ratingValue": "2.6",
                      "ratingCount": "8864"
                    },
                    "offers": {
                      "@type": "Offer",
                      "price": "1.00",
                      "priceCurrency": "USD"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    "seller": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "B2B Software Sales Company",
        "url": "https://www.b2b-software-global.net",
        "logo": "https://www.b2b-software-global.net/logo.png"
    },

    "sameAs": [
        "https://twitter.com/example-software-company",
        "https://linkedin.com/example-software-company",
        "https://facebook.com/example-software-company"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such detailed examples!

It was my initial idea as well to cite the Company as the `parentOrganization`. But, I walked away from it as I thought it would not be correct to use the `Organization` markup for the software brand, which is not technically a company. But I guess it's not that crucial?

Comment: @YaroslavKladko I do not think it is crucial, as there is no rule that says an Organization has to be a technical company. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using the type `Thing` as an embed to the property `brand`. This contradicts **[Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/product?hl=en#product-properties)**:

*brand
Brand or Organization
The brand of the product.
Note: If you set the type to anything other than Brand or Organization, we will understand it to be a Thing. This is not specific enough, so we highly recommend using the type Brand or Organization instead.*

Comment: When I was checking in with the schema.org documentation, the properties `name` and `description` (from the example) were under the `Thing` type for [Brand](https://schema.org/Brand). I thought it would be correct to use it instead as I'm not very profound with the markup. Thanks for the tip!